# Why is the examples link for nodejs examples returning a 404: https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-nodejs-client/blob/master/examples

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

This link is not working: https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-nodejs-client/blob/master/examples

Any other links for this purpose?

Comment: Because the link is not available :)

Comment: address is now https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 2):

Yes, try this link. It appears they [renamed](https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-nodejs-client/commit/8779ac6ccb71be123dc83552ceb21da9a7658c45) it to [samples](https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples). :)

In future it's better to bookmark a link to the *whole* repo, not to a separate folder as it may change and GitHub doesn't do redirecting for that unlike for changing username or *repo* name.